# Is there a way in C++ to make scoped global variables?

Tags: c++, scope, global

Let's say I have a program which uses n big modules:

A) Network/Communication

B) I/O files

C) I/O database

D) GUI

E) ...

Of course, a list of modules could be bigger.

Let's say I want to have some global variable, but with a scope limited to a single module.

As an example, let's say that I/O database module will consist of 10 classes, each representing each table in a database, but it needs some `global const` state like `Name of table A`, `Columns of table A` etc. (as it is a relational database, in table D I may need to use table A).
It is also obvious, that I do not need to access these table names through Network/Communication module. Is there a way to make a variable "globally" accessible only for some part of classes?

Just for clarification - I know that "Global for some part" is a contradiction, but my idea is that I want to keep the accessibility(no need of pointer passing to each object), while limiting the place from where it can be called (for example, limit from global to module scope)

Comment: Is namespace not enough? Unless you have a hard limit like "A must not access B, but C could access B".

Comment: Isn't that's what `static` keyword is for?

Comment: You don't need globals for that, I strongly advise you to learn about dependency injection. Basically you have one "factory" module. And each module has an interface on you can inject an interface that has getters to access the centralized data. (e.g. members of a n instance of a class).  This also allows you to test the independent modules using mocks and stubs (e.g. a test class that returns other values).

Comment: @PKramer is also right, its also know as [Policy Based Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design#Policy-based_design) to C++ programmers.

Comment: @LouisGo namespace is the best solution I have come up with so far, but it doesn't really separate modules that much. There would be no difference in using `Database::TableAName()` in either module. (And `using namespace Database` in each database class is probably not the best solution, especially when it could be nested)
@Kaihaku I am not sure if I understand correctly, but I would need to inherit in each `Database` class from a single class which holds static variables, I am not sure about this solution
@PKramer This is interesting, I am going to make more research about it

Comment: Dependency injection should be better than namespace. You may control the scope of each module, but if you already have a huge project and using mostly global singletons.. Then it will be so much pain.

Comment: For me it looks like a general design failure. If have some data which is only related to some other data or code, it is, per definition, NOT global. You can derive from classes with static data inside, which makes the instance accessible from all these class instances and all of them see the SAME data but others have no access to it. To give you a real answer, your question is to broad.

Comment: C++20 modules might help.

Comment: @Klaus As I have said, I see a contradiction in `scoped global`, as I don't really need a pure global variable (global is accessible from every part of code). Wouldn't it be a bad code if I have static abstract variable which I will inherit from, and it will have 10 fields `TableXName`, 10 lists `XColumnList`, and probably some other not related to tables variables(but related to databases)? I would like to separate the objects that are logically separable, but it would make me to inherit more than one class(maybe it is not that wrong?).

Comment: I can't understand why `namespace` is not enough. Put your variables into a header file containing a namespace, if you need these variables, include the header file, otherwise, do not include the header file. Can't this help you? Please show us a minimal specific example if necessary.

Comment: @Lidbey Dependency injection isn't "interesting" its a vital property of a design that's going to last and will be flexible enough to allow maintenance (refactoring) of your system at a later point in time. What probably triggers me is that you use the words "big modules". This doesn't sound like a small home project

Comment: Thank you for your comments, those actually solves my problems - you were right that the problem was about the design. I will stay with namespace as for now and try to refactor it into a factory with dependency injection(and try to begin with it in new projects). I am not sure if somebody would like to place an answer, so I can mark the question as solved.

Comment: @Lidbey You're welcome. If you have any questions remaing let me know.

Comment: First remark: It is not per se a "no go" to inherit from multiple classes. Dependency injection in its classical form uses a pointer to a service or a factory to generate service objects. Well, I believe in your case, all and everything is already known during compile time. ( There is no dependency change in runtime nor your database tables will change in runtime). As this, a factory is a wrong pattern and DI should be implemented with CRTP instead of runtime pointers to services. But, quite clear, I am not really aware of all your design stuff/problems and data schemes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need globals for that, I strongly advise you to learn about dependency injection. Basically you have one "factory" module. And each module has an interface on you can inject an interface that has getters to access the centralized data. (e.g. members of a n instance of a class). This also allows you to test the independent modules using mocks and stubs (e.g. a test class that returns other values). –